# Safari not always firing animationend with chained animation

Tags: javascript, css, animation, safari

I dont know what im doin wrong here.
My animation worked fine till last days. After debugging ive seen the animationend event is not getting fired on my last two animations in the chain.

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/bn1krph7/

```
<div class="welcome-container"><div class="welcome-logo"><img src="https://placehold.it/250x250" class="welcome-avatar"></div><div class="welcome-title-container"><span class="welcome-title">Welcome, </span><span class="welcome-user">User!</span></div></div>

$(function() {
    var container = $('.welcome-container');
var logo = document.querySelector('.welcome-logo');

logo.addEventListener('animationend', function(e) {
    console.log(e.animationName);
}, false);;

setTimeout(function() {
    container.addClass('visible');      
  }, 1000)
});

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.welcome-container {
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;

  &.visible {
    transition-property: opacity;
    transition-duration: 450ms;
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
  }
}

.welcome-logo, .welcome-title-container {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
}

.welcome-logo {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 16px solid #434c53;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  transform-origin: center center;
  width: 126px;
  height: 126px;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0) scale(0.17);
  top: 8.4%;
}

.welcome-avatar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
}

.welcome-user {
  opacity: 0;
  color: #434c53;
}

.welcome-title {
  opacity: 0;
  color: #6D7579;
}

.welcome-title-container {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 15px;
  top: 63.3%;
}

.welcome-container.visible {
  .welcome-logo {
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-duration: .6s, .2s, .3s, .1s, .1s, .3s;
    animation-name: logoMoveDown, logoSmall1, logoBig1, logoNormal, logoBig2, logoFadeOut;
    animation-delay: 0s, 0.1s, 0.3s, 0.6s, 3.1s, 3.2s;
  }

  .welcome-avatar {
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-duration: .2s;
    animation-name: fade-in;
    animation-delay: 0.3s;
  }

  .welcome-user {
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-duration: 1s, .3s;
    animation-name: fade-in, fade-out;
    animation-delay: 1s, 3.2s;
  }

  .welcome-title {
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-duration: 1s, .3s;
    animation-name: fade-in, fade-out;
    animation-delay: 0.8s, 3.2s;
  }
}

@keyframes logoMoveDown {
  from{
    top: 8.4%;
  }
  to {
    top: 39%;
  }
}

@keyframes logoSmall1 {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0) scale(0.17);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0) scale(0.1);
  }
}

@keyframes logoBig1 {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0) scale(0.1);
    border-width: 16px;
  }
  50% {
    border-width: 3px;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0) scale(1.2);
    border-width: 3px;
  }
}

@keyframes logoNormal {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0) scale(1.2);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0) scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes logoBig2 {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0) scale(1);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0) scale(1.2);
  }
}

@keyframes logoFadeOut {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0) scale(1.2);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0) scale(0.2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes fade-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fade-out {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Chrome is working fine. Safari (9.1.2) doesnt work!
Another funny issue ive found: With alt+tab out and back in the animation will get called to end aslong there is no iframe usage. So you cant see in the fiddle demo.

Comment: I can only speak for Safari 9.1.1, but both Chrome and Safari log *7 steps*: `logoSmall1 fade-in logoMoveDown logoBig1 logoNormal logoBig2 logoFadeOut` when running the fiddle.

Comment: @insertusernamehere thx for testing this in v9.1.1! So it seems to be a bug only in v9.1.2.